# Partial differential equation .

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm new to the forum and I hate to be the guy who asks for people to solve my homework but I've been trying to solve the follow exercise and I've been stuck for hours :(. Partial equation is probably the most difficult aspect of differential equations for me...

1. if $F$ and $G$ are twice differentiable functions, show that $u(x,y)=F(2x-y)+G(x-y)$ (2) is a solution to $U_{xx}+3 U_{xy}+2U_{yy}=0$ (1)
2. Use a linear change of variables to show that every solution to (1) has the form (2).
3. Find the solution to (1) that satisfies the initial conditions: $u(x,0)=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$ and $u_y(x,0)=0$ for all $x$

Comment: as you've been stuck for hours it means you've done some work before asking, which is _perfect_! Please can you add to your post what you've tried, and what you're stuck on.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**.  Partially differentiating something like $F(2x-y)$ is not really very much different from simple one-variable problems.  Just take it step by step and I think you will get it.

(1) Can you differentiate $\sin(2x-1)$?
(2) Can you differentiate $\sin(2x-y)$ with respect to $x$, taking $y$ to be a constant?
(3) So, if $F$ is an unspecified function, can you differentiate $F(2x-y)$ with respect to $x$, taking $y$ to be a constant?

If you are still not sure about (3), try repeating (1) and (2), replacing $\sin(2x-y)$ by $\tan(2x-y)$, or $e^{(2x-y)}$, or $(2x-y)^{13}$ or something.

In every case you will find that the derivative of $F(2x-y)$ is $2G(2x-y)\,$, where $G$ is a function with a certain connection to $F$.  Can you spot what the connection is?

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I differentiated sin(2x-1) and i think the solution is  2cos(2x-1) and the solution for sin(2x-y) is probably 2cos(2x-y).But i'm stuck again lol. I don't understand what's the value of F(2x-y) now that i've differentiated the first two. Anyway,i'll do a little research :)

Comment: Have added a bit more to my answer - see if that gives you the clue.

Comment: It was a poor choice to name the derivative of $F$ as $G$ in your last sentence, because the original problem also has a function named G, and OP probably got confused by that.